# picker self given a Thread 1 ERROR

Tags: swift2, xcode7, uipickerview

I'm new in coding and i'm loving it, i'm trying to use a picker but i'm getting this error. I did just the same i did in my other project but now it's not working...
May this being happening because i have more than 1 view controller?

her is my code, the error is in the picture i've uploaded

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  Lucky Numbershhh
//
//  Created by Rafael Esper on 5/19/16.
//  Copyright © 2016 mudo25. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {


    // Escolhe os tipos de números


    @IBOutlet weak var picker: UIPickerView!
    var tipoNumeros = ["Números Aleatórios","Números mais sorteados","Números Menos sorteados"]



    var arrayMegaSena = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60]
    var arrayMegaSenaMais = [4,5,10,13,17,23,24,28,29,33,41,42,49,51,52,53,54]
    var arrayMegaMenos = [3,9,14,15,19,21,22,25,26,39,40,48,55,57]

    var arrayQuina = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80]
    var arrayQuinaSenaMais = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14]
    var arrayQuinaMenos = [69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80]

    var resultado = []

    var quantosNumeros = ("5")
    var tipoJogo = ("0")
    var tipoNumerosEscolhidos = ("Números Aleatórios")

    @IBOutlet weak var LabelQuantosNumeros: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var LabelResultado: UILabel!




    // Escolhe Mega ou Quina


    @IBAction func BotaoMegaOuQuina(sender: UISegmentedControl) {tipoJogo = String(sender.selectedSegmentIndex)
        tipoJogo = String(sender.selectedSegmentIndex)
    }


    @IBOutlet weak var ResultadoMegaOuQuina: UISegmentedControl!




    // Escolhe Quantos números

    @IBAction func BotaoQuantosNumeros(sender: AnyObject) {
        LabelQuantosNumeros.text = String(Int(ResultadoQuantosNumeros.value))
        quantosNumeros = String(Int(ResultadoQuantosNumeros.value))

    }

    @IBOutlet weak var ResultadoQuantosNumeros: UIStepper!









    // Sorteio dos números

    @IBAction func GeraNumeros(sender: AnyObject) {
    }




    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


self.picker.delegate = self
self.picker.dataSource = self

    }


    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }


    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return tipoNumeros.count
    }


    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return tipoNumeros[row]
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
       tipoNumerosEscolhidos = String(tipoNumeros[row])
    }





    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just add `UINavigationControllerDelegate` like this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource,UINavigationControllerDelegate {
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jack, but still crashing!!!! Any other suggestion? I've deleted and have done all over again but still not working... Is that because it is in the third view controller and not on the first one?

Comment: At the output the message is   fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)